# Return Date Range based on the No. of Days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to return date range as the 4th column based on the `NoOfDays` in 3rd column with the following sql query.

For ex:

if it is `70` as `NoOfDays`, it should return `61-70` as `DateRange`

if it is `51` as `NoOfDays`, it should return `51-60` as `DateRange`

if it is `100` as `NoOfDays`, it should return `91-100` as `DateRange`

if it is `174` as `NoOfDays`, it should return `171-180` as `DateRange`

```
DECLARE @V_START INT = 1;
DECLARE @V_END INT = 10;

SELECT GETDATE() CurrentDate, TASK_ASSIGNED_DTM,
       DATEDIFF(DAY, TASK_ASSIGNED_DTM, GETDATE()) NoOfDays, (CAST(@V_START AS VARCHAR(10))+'-'+CAST(@V_END AS VARCHAR(10))) AS DateRange                       
FROM Table
```

Comment: could you give us the result when you're running this query: `SELECT GETDATE() CurrentDate, TASK_ASSIGNED_DTM,
       DATEDIFF(DAY, TASK_ASSIGNED_DTM, GETDATE()) NoOfDays, (CAST(@V_START AS VARCHAR(10))+'-'+CAST(@V_END AS VARCHAR(10))) AS DateRange                       FROM Table`

Comment: How exactly is the DateRange determined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this can work for you?

You can use *modulo* to determin how to format your range, like so:

```
with sample as (
  select * from (values(70),(51),(100),(174))x(n)
)
select Iif(n % 10 = 0, Concat(n - 9, '-', n), Concat(n - (n % 10) + 1, '-', n - (n % 10) + 10)) as Range
from sample;
```

You could apply this to your current query (untested of course) like so:

```
select GetDate() CurrentDate, TASK_ASSIGNED_DTM,
  n.NoOfDays, 
  Iif(n.NoOfDays % 10 = 0, 
    Concat(n.NoOfDays - 9, '-', n.NoOfDays), 
    Concat( n.NoOfDays - (n.NoOfDays % 10) + 1, '-', n.NoOfDays - (n.NoOfDays % 10) + 10)
  ) as Daterange                  
from table
cross apply(values(datediff(day, TASK_ASSIGNED_DTM, getdate())))n(NoOfDays);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use a generic TIER table.   It reduces the number of touch-points (removes from code) and offers a more data-driven approach for the business logic and subsequent evolutions.

Here is a dramatically simplified approach.   The table variable @Tiers should be a physical table.

**Example**

```
Declare @Tiers Table ([Grp] varchar(50),[Dsc] varchar(50),[R1] int,[R2] int)
Insert Into @Tiers Values 
 ('DPD','Current',0,30)
,('DPD','31-50',31,50)
,('DPD','51-60',51,60)
,('DPD','61-70',61,70)
,('DPD','71-80',71,80)
,('DPD','81-90',81,90)
,('DPD','91-100',91,100)
,('DPD','101-170',101,170)
,('DPD','171-180',171,180)
,('DPD','181+',181,9999)
 

Declare @YourTable Table ([TASK_ASSIGNED_DTM] date)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('2022-07-15')
,('2022-08-29')
,('2022-12-03')
,('2023-01-02')
 

Select A.*
      ,B.Dsc
 From  @YourTable A
 Join  @Tiers     B on B.Grp='DPD' and datediff(DAY,TASK_ASSIGNED_DTM,getdate()) between R1 and R2
```

**Results**

```
TASK_ASSIGNED_DTM   Dsc
2022-07-15          171-180
2022-08-29          101-170
2022-12-03          31-50
2023-01-02          Current
```